# Using customize font on TextField component

Tags: material-ui

**Using Material-UI v1:**

How do I change the font of a `TextField`? I'm trying to apply a Roboto Mono font to it.

What I currently have is

```
import 'typeface-roboto-mono';
...
<TextField
  ...
  inputProps={{ fontFamily: 'Roboto Mono' }}
/>
```

But that's not working.

Thanks.